# How to @Autowire list of beans by Trait?

Tags: spring, scala, autowired, traits

I try to @Autowire list of beans by Trait and I get error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [scala.collection.immutable.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [scala.collection.immutable.List] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [scala.collection.immutable.List] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Is possible to do it like in Java? Below my Scala code:

```
trait ProductDataProvider {
   def collect()
}

@Component
class SomeProvider() extends ProductDataProvider {
   override def collect(): Unit = ...
}

@Component
class ProductDataSourceFactory @Autowired()(providers: List[ProductDataProvider])() {
   def get(source: ProductDataSource.Value): ProductDataProvider = ...
}
```

I will be glad if you point me good direction.

Comment: probably spring doesn't work with scala's `List`, try using `java.util.List`

Comment: Thank you a lot! That's resolve my issue!

Answer (score 2):

Spring is a Java framework and it doesn't work with Scala collections, replace usage of `scala.collection.immutable.List` class to `java.util.List` in a place where you want to inject a list of beans.